# OpenGL: Zoom adaptive grid lines

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make a viewport grid like the ones seen in most 3D Modelers where zooming adjusts the grid spacing so lines don't get too dense or too far apart. For example zooming out changes the spacing from 1m to 2m then 5m then 10m and 20m etc. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Here it's usually not as complicated as you might think it would be initially. For example, you might notice that panning and orbiting the camera has no effect on that grid density, even though the nearest distance from grid plane to viewer could be changing. Likewise, changing FOV has no effect on the chosen grid unit size, even though ideally perhaps it should given how it can significantly skew and narrow the view.

So there's usually just this basic, 1-dimensional kind of notion of `zoom distance` relative to the look at target (camera pivot), and it involves no fancy math, just adjusting a scalar that affects values passed to `glScale` or `glTranslate`, e.g.

As it increases, so does the unit size used for drawing the grid (and possibly snapping to it), and here it's often not some brilliant, mathematical solution but just a linear mapping from that zoom distance to hard-coded unit sizes like 1mm, 2mm, 5mm, 10mm, 20mm, 50mm, 1cm, etc.

These kinds of things usually aren't the result of some algorithmic paper but just a developer/designer sitting down and tweaking things until they look/feel about right. If you're trying to develop a 3D software, I'd recommend never to overlook this basic solution for things related to user interaction because it's easy to become convinced in 3D that everything has to be complicated and have a lot of research and a perfectly-accurate mathematical solution behind it. For the UI parts, you can get away with far more informal solutions.

Sometimes the formal mathematical solutions for these UI visuals/interactions don't work quite as well in practice as these kludged solutions, as you might have noticed in the user interfaces coming from the more academic realm (which are usually much smarter mathematically and algorithmically for these things, but actually less intuitive).

Comment: Very well said! By now I've realised that there is no specific way to go when it comes to 3D software design. It seems trivial to produce something like this at first but its giving me a hard time. For example I have a zoom factor that starts as 1 (no zoom) and zooms in near 0. I tried adding hard coded values but that spacing effect seems almost infinite. You can zoom out from millimetres all the way to kilometres.

Comment: So I'm currently trying to come up with some formula that takes in consideration the zoom factor to produce a valid grid line spacing. I'm currently not using glScale, the grid is basically redrawn on each render with the line spacing passed as a parameter (for example 0.5 to draw a line every half unit). I will give it another try and see what I come up with.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that the adaptive grid unit chosen like `2 meters` or `5 meters` is really just a form of _snapping_. So to avoid getting overwhelmed trying to do too much at once, I recommend first finding a formula that maps the way you're dealing with this zoom factor to a grid unit size gives intuitive unit sizes _without snapping_ (ex: allowing grid unit sizes like 0.372572913 -- don't even worry about what that means in real world units just yet, just try to make it match your zoom level intuitively). Then you can add the snapping and real world units as a finishing touch.

Comment: So then it just becomes totally about experimenting with formulas that map your zoom factor to unit size. I'm not quite sure how you're dealing with zoom with a range from [1,0], but you can try things like `zoom_factor * zoom_factor`, `-log(1 - zoom_factor)`, etc. Since these things are typically independent of things like FOV, you can get away with just fiddling around with a magic formula until it looks right at any distance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of 3D software are you trying to create? A modeler, animator, compositor, production renderer, all of the above?

Comment: I'm creating a 3D modeler. I must say it's a lot of fun in the making and it's starting to look very good (I always thought that known modelers lack a nice user interface) but as we said there is just so many ways to do a single thing that one can get overwhelmed. Do you have any experience in such software or similar?

Comment: @DanG I worked on one a while back called 'LightWave', but no longer with that team -- flying solo now.

Comment: @DanG For a modeler the main tricky part is just all this setup overhead in the beginning to get that kind of host environment: your mesh system, viewports, cameras, GPU rendering, etc. Then there's the general environment-level concepts you want to support like falloffs, pivots/centers, coordinate systems, etc. But then it's really fun when you have all that done, and you're just looking at adding modeling tools.

Comment: Oh wow! I was using Lightwave for quite a while (I think since version 5.5). I think the team left NewTek and is now making Modo. I think my concerns at the moment is basically on the mesh data structures. I've switched to a basic indexed structure (as you noted in another post), but there is just so many little questions especially on how to support triangles, quads and polygons along with materials. Ex: for each material find and draw all the triangles, then do the same for quads and polygons then move on to the next material? or..

Comment: convert the mesh into triangles witch is convenient when smooth shading and draw lines in the other viewports (maybe by setting the edge flag).. I'm just trying a whole bunch of stuff. I added the OpenGL profiler to some know software like LW and saw that most of the drawing is done with glDrawArrays (not glDrawElements) and in no part do they draw Polygons or Quads. It's always Triangles or lines although it feels like you are working with Quads and Polygons.

Comment: Maybe we could go into the chat. I wonder how to trigger it -- seems like you need a set number of posts. There's multiple ways to handle this problem based on your needs. The easiest is to not bother with tessellation and just render everything in immediate mode, but that gets quite slow as you approach those million+ poly meshes.

Comment: Hmm, still no chat option. But if you are doing this kind of general-purpose polygonal modeler, I'd recommend keeping a tessellated list of 3-tuple vertex indices per polygon to keep track of the tessellated results. Depending on your speed/visual quality desire, you might update the tessellation even when points are deformed or do it periodically (like when the user finishes interacting) or only when polygons are created.

Comment: ... the triangles are useful even for non-rendering purposes like ray/triangle intersection with planar guarantees.

Comment: Ok I tried to go into chat and It says I don't have enough reputation points. I just started using stack overflow in the past couple of weeks.

Comment: One difficulty with a mesh system is that it's effectively a complex graph data structure, and you get tempted to create variable-sized lists storing variable-sized lists of things (ex: a mesh storing a list of polygons, with each polygons storing a list of vertices). That structural overhead of having so lists and sub-lists can start to become a problem very quickly, and you'll typically want to flatten it all down and lose some of the structure to mitigate the overhead. Then it's tricky if you do it contiguously to allow removals of elements -- here it helps to think of it as an allocator.

Comment: Hmm, I know -- I think I can edit the post on the question you asked about popular mesh representations and discuss some issues you might face there and possible strategies to deal with them.

Comment: That is my problem I would say. Right now I'm holding a list of faces with indices pointing to the vertices, normals and texture coordinates and a material id. The reason is, I want to know if the face has 3, 4 or more sides so I know how to draw them.

Comment: Oh good, that would be great. I can even send you an email or anything. This discussion is very helpful

Comment: Hmm, you have anything like Skype or Google Chat or anything like that? It's interesting to find a fellow 3D modeling dev.