# Threejs: How to create zoomable adaptive grid helper

Tags: three.js, 3d, grid

How do I make a **zoom adaptive** *grid-helper* in threejs, neither getting too dense to be rendered blank, nor getting too sparse to be not completely not rendered?

```
function addGrid({scene}) {
    let gridSize = 200000;
    const grid = new THREE.GridHelper( gridSize, gridSize/100, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
    grid.name = 'gridHelper';
    grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
    grid.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add( grid );
}
```

Should I just use the control's `change` listener and hard code a bunch of values as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511908/opengl-zoom-adaptive-grid-lines), to rerender the grid helper when crossing those values, or is there a neat mathematical way to do the same?

Also, I couldn't find any explicit attribute (like `grid.divisions`) which I can alter, wouldn't it be inefficient to remove the object and add it to the scene?

How do I do this?

Comment: `GridHelper` doesn't have a public api for modifying the geometry after instantiation, so you need to either recreate the grid on control change (wouldn't be too inefficient if you only recreate when you actually need to) or create a custom grid geometry from scratch that allows for easy modifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use the same grid and set the scale, maybe 2 grids

```
        const gridLevel = Math.log10(zoom * zoomAdjust);
        const gridFract = THREE.Math.euclideanModulo(gridLevel, 1);
        const gridZoom = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(gridLevel));    

        grid1.scale.setScalar(gridZoom);
        grid1.material.opacity = Math.max((1 - gridFract) * 1);

        grid2.scale.setScalar(gridZoom * 10);
        grid2.material.opacity = Math.max(gridFract * 10) - 1;
        grid2.visible = grid2.material.opacity > 0;
```

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  const zoomAdjust = 5;  // change to adjust when things start/end. Try 5 or .5 for example
  const zoomElem = document.querySelector('#zoom');

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 1000;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  function makeGrid() {
    const grid = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 200);
    grid.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(grid);
    return grid;
  }
  const grid2 = makeGrid();
  const grid1 = makeGrid();

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  let zoom = 1;

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    zoomElem.textContent = zoom.toFixed(4);
    
    camera.near = zoom / 100;
    camera.far = zoom * 100;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    
    camera.position.set(zoom * -10, zoom * 5, zoom * -10);
    
    const gridLevel = Math.log10(zoom * zoomAdjust);
    const gridFract = THREE.Math.euclideanModulo(gridLevel, 1);
    const gridZoom = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(gridLevel));    

    grid1.scale.setScalar(gridZoom);
    grid1.material.opacity = Math.max((1 - gridFract) * 1);
    
    grid2.scale.setScalar(gridZoom * 10);
    grid2.material.opacity = Math.max(gridFract * 10) - 1;
    grid2.visible = grid2.material.opacity > 0;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();
  
  window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const amount = e.deltaY;
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      zoom *= 1 - THREE.Math.clamp(e.deltaY / -500, 0, 1);
    } else {
      zoom *= 1 + THREE.Math.clamp(e.deltaY / 500, 0, 1);
    }
    zoom = THREE.Math.clamp(zoom, 0.0001, 10000);
    render();
  }, {passive: false});
  window.addEventListener('resize', render);

}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
#hud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<div id="hud">zoom: <span id="zoom"></span></div>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this i have to say is quite brilliant :)